# PHP Include works in North America, but not working in Panama or South Africa?

Tags: php, mysql, include

I am having issues with people from certain area's of the world logging into a password restricted area of my website. I use an include to log into the database throughout my code so that if i need to make a change i don't need to change a hundred scripts each time. People had been reporting that they were getting the following error on login:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/ifalpao/public_html/members/login.php on line 15

I didn't believe it was a real issue until i experienced the problem while in Panama recently. Let me know what i am doing wrong here...

Here is the code for the include:

```
<?php
    //Connect to DB
    $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");

    //Check Connection
    if ($connection->connect_errno){ echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error; }

?>
```

Here is the code in the login script:

```
    //Connect to Database
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/members/connection.php');

    //compose sql statement
    $sql="SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE email=\"".$username."\";";

    //Retrieve Password
    $results = $connection->query($sql);
```

Line 15 is:

```
$results = $connection->query($sql);
```

The crazy thing is that this works in North America (Montreal, Boston, Miami verified) and in Europe (England, France verified), but does not work in other countries such as Africa and Panama(both verified).

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: There are all in the same Server? Or Divided By Servers?

Comment: This sounds like a server issue, not code related. Make sure they are all running the same settings as your NA and EU servers.

Comment: Yes they are all on the same server, just different folders. I have always hardcoded the location using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']... and in North America i have never run into issues... Just now i am working on an international project, and it is not working for everyone.

Comment: @chaseC all the code is on one server

Comment: Could it be that the username that's being passed in (side note: please change your code to use PDO instead of passing the username directly into the SQL statement) is in a different character set from users in different countries? (another side note, Africa isn't a country)

Comment: Are you certain the include is working properly for all locations? The fatal error tells you $connection is not an object. var_dump the connection, and the include return value to see what happens.

Comment: @CanSpice I have tried to log in while in Panama personally using my usual username/password combo and it failed there, but works here in Montreal. A colleague of mine has tried from Somewhere in africa(i'm not sure where) and could not login, but when i use his credentials here i am able to log in without problems.

Comment: @tom It appears to not include the connection file in certain countries... which baffles me since the script is executed server side.

Comment: Check the case. If you're including based on country through your DOCUMENT_ROOT environment variable, it could be failing because of casing. E.g. include("UK/members/connection.php") instead of include("uk/members/connection.php").

Comment: @tom I use lower case everything to avoid case errors.

Comment: You may also want to look into SetEnv (assuming you're using Apache). You could use this in each of your virtual hosts to set your own custom variable, e.g. `SetEnv MY_LOCALE uk`. This way, if your document root changes (or you have two locations that use the same locale), you can use the same environment variable. $_SERVER['MY_LOCALE'].

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] isn't actually what you're expecting it to be. For the locations that don't work, what does echoing the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] tell you?

Comment: The include library is a fixed one(the path never changes per country)... i was worried i wasn't getting the correct fixed location, so i echoed out the location, and everything checks out...

Comment: (as an aside to one of my side-notes, you're using `mysqli` which has support for prepared statements, so you should change your code to use those instead of using string concatenation to form your SQL)

Answer (score 3):

check for utf8, maybe you are typing in a different collation

Comment: Testing this possibility now... Waiting on a reply from someone from the affected areas.